# document.form[0] is Null or Not an Object error when hiding a text field in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am hiding a TextBoxin my aspx page like this:

*myField.visible=false;*

Now I have a DropDown as well which tries to access the TextBox on IndexChange. The problem is, it cant access the hiffen TextBox and I am getting **document.form[0] is Null or Not an Object**. How can I solve that? Is the some check for that in JavaScript?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Please provide sample code. When you set visible to false on the server, nothing is rendered and you cannot access it with javascript, but I'm not sure this is your case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access the first form in the document via its numerical index (hint: You shouldn't be, the id attribute is very handy, then you are looking for the first in a group of *forms*, not the first in a group of *form*.

```
document.forms[0] // It is plural
```

Comment: The is JavaScript added to the DropDown control which is called each time the index changed. The JS code tries to get the value from the text box like this:

*document.forms[0].ctl00_Content_TX_myField.value*

Here it throws the error.

Comment: Err, so the code you put in the question is wrong, and my answer would correct it, and you've downvoted this answer because of that?

Comment: If your code says `document.forms` then your error message would not say `document.form`